# Xamarin datatemplate with many rows

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I have a listview and a datatemplate.

```
 <ListView x:Name="list"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"
                     HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell> 
                      <Grid Padding="5"> 
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions> 

                          <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition> 
                          <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition> 
                          <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition> 
                          <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition> 
                          </Grid.RowDefinitions> 

                             <Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition> 
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition> 
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>   

                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="First"></Label> 
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding First}"></Label>

                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Second"></Label> 
                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Second}"></Label>

                            <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Third"></Label> 
                            <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Third}"></Label>

                            <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="Fourth"></Label> 
                            <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Forth}"></Label>

                      </Grid> 
                  </ViewCell> 
              </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
```

The problem here is that only the first two rows are displayed. Is there maybe some limitation to a viewCell that only lets it show two rows?

Is there maybe a better way to achieve what I am trying to do? Can I maybe use a table inside the datatemplate? Thank you

Comment: Why did you set the  HorizontalOptions="Center" ? 
If your page contains only this list, make it HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Adding to `ListView` a `RowHeight` definition.

For example, I would try something like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="list"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"
                 HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 RowHeight="100">
  ...
  </ListView>
```

Comment: Thank you,The RowHeight did it!